# databricks editor UI issues

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, aws-databricks

When I click on a databricks results display (to copy it), the page refreshes and does a page up. And then it comes back to the same cell.
Also when I do ctrl+C on the display cell(copy), the notebook starts execution!

What am I doing wrong? Did I change any setting?

Comment: Could you share a link to the notebook in question?

Answer (score 0):

All notebook tasks are supported by UI actions, but you can also perform many tasks using keyboard shortcuts. Toggle the shortcut display by clicking the Keyboard Icon [image].

> To copy the cell you need to use `Ctrl+Alt+C`.

[image]

For more details, refer [Azure Databricks - Use notebooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/notebooks-use).

Comment: Not to copy the whole cell. But a small text in the display results. Selected + copy

Comment: Could you please share the screenshot which are referring too?

Comment: It is a text from the results cell. I will send it later